# GWT - Datagrid : Keyboard single selection, when multi selection is enabled

Tags: gwt, datagrid, gwt-celltable, gwt-2.5, gwt-2.4

When I enable keyboard selection policy and multi selection on `DataGrid` I encountered this problem.

**Case 1** : Multi selection through mouse and keyboard

When I want to select more than one row through mouse, I hold `Ctrl` key or `Shift` key and this works fine. Through keyboard by default, this action is provided by `spacebar`. When I want to select serially through keyboard combination of `shift` key and `spacebar` does the trick.

**Case 2** : Single selection through mouse and keyboard (*This is where the problem starts*)

When I want to select a single row through mouse, I just do a `left click`. If I don't hold either of `ctrl` of `shift` key and do a `left click`, even if the multiple rows are selected, it will get deselected and only the current row gets selected. This is the expected behavior and I don't have any issue with it.

***But the same thing is not achievable through keyboard.*** There is no way to select a single row through keyboard. If I press `spacebar` a row gets selected and if I press the `spacebar` again on some other row without `shift/ctrl` key, it gets multi selected and previous selected row doesn't get deselected.

**My question is** : How to achieve single selection through keyboard similar to that of mouse?

**EDIT** : I [opened this issue in gwt issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8065). I hope they respond to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to [use](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#setSelectionModel%28com.google.gwt.view.client.SelectionModel,%20com.google.gwt.view.client.CellPreviewEvent.Handler%29) a [custom selection event manager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html#createCustomManager%28com.google.gwt.view.client.DefaultSelectionEventManager.EventTranslator%29) whose [translator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.EventTranslator.html) returns the appropriate value for the behavior you want from [`clearCurrentSelection`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.EventTranslator.html#clearCurrentSelection%28com.google.gwt.view.client.CellPreviewEvent%29).

The [default behavior](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.5.1-rc1/user/src/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.java#527) is to always add/remove from selection from the keyboard, and use the control or meta key to toggle whether to clear the current selection when using the mouse.

Comment: I will definitely try this approach. I have a question though. Shouldn't my expectation should be default behaviour? Anywhere in the web or desktop application, unless you hold on some additional key like ctrl or shift, shouldn't it be always a single selection? Should I create a issue in gwt issue list regarding the same or is there any specific reason why it is designed like that

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. Feel free to open an issue, but be prepared to wait for a long time. Those kind of things, particularly when there are workarounds, are lower priority. Back you issue with _on the wild_ examples of what you think should be the correct behavior.